# Query that returns all elements where one or more elements in List match field Java MongoDB Driver 3.7.1

Tags: java, mongodb, filter

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to design a specific query.

I got a list of stations with names that is chosen by a user at runtime, stored in a List. That is to say the list size and content might change but the type is always the same.
I got data elements in my database with similar station name.

I want to design a query that finds all documents where the station name matches one in the list.

Lets say i got a list of station names `List<String> StationNames = ["Bob", "Allan"]` and fields with the following station names

```
{station_name: "Bob"} ,  {station_name: "Allan"} , {station_name: "Steve"} , {station_name: "Patricia"}
```

The query would then return the two first documents because Bob is in the list and Allan is in the list.

How would i design this query? My problem is designing it so it works dynamically based on the Strings in the list,  if the List length didnt change i would add a eq(stationName, StationNames[i]) or i would make several queries and add the result to a single list but i assume it is more efficient to do it in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to write the query:

```
// The input list
List<String> stationNames = [ "Bob", "Allan" ];  

// The query
Document filter = new Document( "station_name", new Document( "$in", stationNames ) );
List<Document> results = new ArrayList<>();
myCollection.find( filter ).into( results );
```

The `results` list will have documents with station names "Bob" and "Allan".